# Azure Durable Functions : Http Trigger error

Tags: python, azure, function

As a newbie in Azure,
I am following Microsoft Azure Function tutorial page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=python
and github page
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-python/tree/master/samples/fan_in_fan_out .

```
**HttpStart code**
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
    client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
    payload: str = json.loads(req.get_body().decode()) # Load JSON post request data
    instance_id = await client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], client_input=payload)

    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    return client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

```
**E2_BackupSiteContent**
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):

    root_directory: str = context.get_input()

    if not root_directory:
        raise Exception("A directory path is required as input")

    files = yield context.call_activity("E2_GetFileList", root_directory)
    tasks = []
    for file in files:
        tasks.append(context.call_activity("E2_CopyFileToBlob", file))
    
    results = yield context.task_all(tasks)
    total_bytes = sum(results)
    return total_bytes

main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

```
**E2_CopyFileToBlob**
import os
import pathlib
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceExistsError

connect_str = os.getenv('AzureWebJobsStorage')

def main(filePath: str) -> str:
    # Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    
    # Create a unique name for the container
    container_name = "backups"
    
    # Create the container if it does not exist
    try:
        blob_service_client.create_container(container_name)
    except ResourceExistsError:
        pass

    # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
    parent_dir, fname = pathlib.Path(filePath).parts[-2:] # Get last two path components
    blob_name = parent_dir + "_" + fname
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

    # Count bytes in file
    byte_count = os.path.getsize(filePath)

    # Upload the created file
    with open(filePath, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data)

    return byte_count
```

```
**E2_GetFileList**
import os
from os.path import dirname
from typing import List

def main(rootDirectory: str) -> List[str]:

    all_file_paths = []
    # We walk the file system
    for path, _, files in os.walk(rootDirectory):
        # We copy the code for activities and orchestrators
        if "E2_" in path:
            # For each file, we add their full-path to the list
            for name in files:
                if name == "__init__.py" or name == "function.json":
                    file_path = os.path.join(path, name)
                    all_file_paths.append(file_path)
    
    return all_file_paths
```

When I http trigger with postman app,
POST http://localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/E2_BackupSiteContent?req="D:\Tmp"
I got the following error messages.

```
[2021-11-12T02:13:42.432Z] Worker process started and initialized.

[2021-11-12T02:13:46.489Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AE48769C'.

[2021-11-12T02:13:52.529Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpStart' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=748996d0-1f84-4597-86ea-768467eb36e3)
[2021-11-12T02:13:52.560Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpStart' (Failed, Id=748996d0-1f84-4597-86ea-768467eb36e3, Duration=5433ms)

[2021-11-12T02:13:52.562Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpStart. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'req'. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.
```

What should I do to solve this problem?
(I tested with Linux and Windows.)

--Added--
[Postman capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n4xS.png)

Comment: In your Httpstart main function, check what is received for your payload variable after reading the req body. In your question you say POST , but passing req as query string, you should pass in the body of the http request, not as QS.

Comment: After that, test with less sized files in that input dir path. May be there is some too large file that causes you the error since Azure function runtime unable to finish reading before timeout.

Comment: @ Anand Sowmithiran  : [Anand Sowmithiran] After putting "logging.info("***") " snippet just before "payload: str = json.loads(req.get_body().decode())" line in the HttpStart code, nothing is printed and those error messages are appeared. In addition, files in the directories are just one text line. That shouldn't take so long. Added postman capture image.

Comment: Nothing is printed , because your request body is blank, you are only sending query string in your URL in postman. You should put json in the body section of your http request in postman tool.

Comment: @Anand Sowmithiran   It is working. Put path string in the body section, not in URL. And root directory should be a root of function project. Last, content-length should be the length of the directory path name. Thank you.

Comment: Good to know, can you accept my below answer. That documentation section as well setting the content length to 20, which matches the length of the payload given in that sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the directory in the query string of the URL, you should pass the path in the HTTP request `body` in the postman tool. The Microsoft doc page itself shows how to do it, see [Run the sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-cloud-backup?tabs=csharp#run-the-sample) section.